# Send XML request and export it in C#

Tags: c#, ajax, xml, request

Is there a way I can send XML request through AJAX, and then catch it on the server side and write it with C# in the text file (the original XML request)?

As for client side, I've sent it with XMLHttpRequest.
As for server side, I don't know how to request XML and how to write it in that format.

```
var xmlData = '<AcquireLicense xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/protocols"><challenge><Challenge xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/protocols/messages"><LA xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/protocols" Id="SignedData" xml:space="preserve"><Version>1</Version><ContentHeader><WRMHEADER xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/PlayReadyHeader" version="4.0.0.0"><DATA><PROTECTINFO><KEYLEN>16</KEYLEN><ALGID>AESCTR</ALGID></PROTECTINFO>...'; 

                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.open('POST', 'test.aspx', true);
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                            alert("OK");
                        } else {
                            alert("error: status: " + xmlhttp.status + " xmlhttp.readyState: " + xmlhttp.readyState);
                        }                           
                    }                       
                }
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
                xmlhttp.send(xmlData);
```

Server side, WebForm test.aspx:

```
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\test.txt"))
    {
        foreach (String key in Request.Form.AllKeys)
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Key: " + key + " Value: " + Request.Form[key]);
        }
    }
```

But I don't get anything in the file because I'm not sure that I'm fetching the XML the right way.

Comment: Try and see, if any problems occur, you can ask here.

Comment: I've sent it, but I have trouble with the server side part, I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are many options available to you if you are using ASP.NET/C# on the backend: http://asp.net/mvc

- You could simply send the xml string as a form post variable. In that case, you can simply have a string parameter to your mvc action method with same name as the form value.
- Or, if you are posting as `text/xml`, you could create a custom model binder: https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/06/24/model-binding-xml-in-asp-net-mvc-3/

Once you have the data, you can use the [`System.IO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io(v=vs.110).aspx) APIs to write the file to the server, or do whatever else you need with that data.

You can get more information about model binding here: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/models/model-binding.html

---

If you are using webforms, you can simply handle the serverside component in the page's codebehind using an event handler:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w2tb12s.aspx

---

*edit:* In response to your edit that added code ... you should take a look at the `InputStream` property of the `Request` property. You are posting the xml as `text/xml`, which means you have to read the request body to get the content:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.inputstream(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I'm closer but it's not solved: when I read the stream as in the example you posted, I get bunch of numbers written in file: "60631201091083211810111411510511111061..."

Comment: How can I export that stream into XML and write it in a file?